# I think I'm making a function call error in the main file, but I can't figure out why

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I would like a candidate to be able to save his informations in a txt file and then the test starts.
I managed to save the personal information of the candidate in a file and run the test but I do not understand why it doesn't print the score.

```
import os

class Student:

    # constructor
    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname

    # ***********************************************************************************************************
    # we create a file called "candidate" in which the candidate enters his personal informations
    # don't forget to add an "r" before the path otherwise it doesn't work
    def candidate_file(self, name, surname):
        with open(r"C:\Users\Intervenant\Desktop\Projets\Python\candidate.txt", "a") as fileCandidate:
            fileCandidate.write("\n" + "Candidat's name : " + name)
            fileCandidate.write("\n" + "Candidat's surname : " + surname)
        
        # we then rename this "candidate" file with its name, all in a .txt file
        # os.rename(r"C:\Users\Intervenant\Desktop\Projets\Python\candidate.txt", name+".txt")

    # ***********************************************************************************************************

    

    # this function takes care of retrieving the answer of a candidate to a question
    def ask_answer(min, max): 
        answer = input("Your choice : ")

        try:
            answer = int(answer)
            if min <= answer <= max:
                return answer
            print("Enter a number between ", min, "and", max)

        except:
            print("Error ! Please enter a number")

        return Student.ask_answer(min, max)

    # ***********************************************************************************************************

    # this function takes care of asking questions to the candidate and counting the number of correct answers
    def ask_question(question):
        # question[1] represents the set of possible answers
        choice = question[1]
        # question[2] represents the correct answer
        rightAnswer = question[2]
        
        print("QUESTION"  )
        print("   ", question[0])

        """
        here len(choice) will calculate the size of the number of possible choices
        in the case of question 1, there are 4 possible choices
        so len(choice) = 3 (from 0 to 3)
        """
        for i in range(len(choice)):
            print(" ", i + 1, "-", choice[i])  # this is to display "2 - True" in question 1 for example

        
        answer = Student.ask_answer(1, len(choice))
        print()

        score = 0
        if choice[answer - 1] == rightAnswer:
            print()
            score += 1
        
        return score

    # ***********************************************************************************************************
    
    def set_questions(self, setQuestions):

        for question in setQuestions:
            Student.ask_question(question)
        
    

    # the set of questions of the exam
    setQuestions=(
        ("What is the output of the following code? print(5 >= 5) ",
            ("5 >= 5","True","False","None"),
            "True"
        ),
        ("Which of these data types is not a base type in Python?",
            ("Lists","Class","Dictionary","Tuples"), 
            "Class"
        ),
        ("What is the output of the following code? min(max(False,-2,-5), 1,5) ",
            ("-5","-2","1","False"),
            "False"
        ),
        ("What is the output of the following code? >>>t = (1, 2, 3) >>>t.append( (4, 5, 6) ) >>>print len(t)",
            ("3","4","6","Error"),
            "Error"
        ),
        ("What is the function that compares the elements of two lists?",
            ("cmp(list1, list2)","eq(list1, list2)","len(list1, list2)","max(list1, list2)"),
            "cmp(list1, list2)"
        )
        )
    # set_questions(setQuestions)
    # print("votre score est : ", ask_question(setQuestions),"sur", len(setQuestions))
```

**I tried to call the setQuestions function in the main but I realized that I had nothing to put in parameter.
so I copied the set of questions (which is in a list) into the main.
But that didn't solve the problem, I don't understand why.**

```
# the main file

from classEtudiant import Student


name = input("Enter your name : ")
surname = input("Enter your surname : ")

print()
print("Welcome to the test Mr/Mrs", name, surname, " !")

# initialize a student
student = Student(name, surname)

# record the candidate's personal informations in a file
student.candidate_file(name, surname)

# launch the test

setQuestions=(
        ("Quelle est la sortie du code suivant? print(5 >= 5) ",
            ("5 >= 5","True","False","None"),
            "True"
        ),
        ("Lequel de ces types de données n’est pas un type de base en Python?",
            ("Lists","Class","Dictionary","Tuples"), 
            "Class"
        ),
        ("Quelle est la sortie du code suivant? min(max(False,-2,-5), 1,5) ",
            ("-5","-2","1","False"),
            "False"
        ),
        ("Quelle est la sortie du code suivant? >>>t = (1, 2, 3) >>>t.append( (4, 5, 6) ) >>>print len(t)",
            ("3","4","6","ERREUR"),
            "ERREUR"
        ),
        ("Quelle est la fonction qui compare les éléments des deux listes?",
            ("cmp(list1, list2)","eq(list1, list2)","len(list1, list2)","max(list1, list2)"),
            "cmp(list1, list2)"
        )
        )
    
student.set_questions(setQuestions)

# print the score of the student
print("Your score is : ", student.ask_question(setQuestions),"/", len(setQuestions))
```

Comment: It does ask the question for me! Can you tell us what is happening when you run the script?

```python main.py
Enter your name : Some
Enter your surname : Guy

Welcome to the test Mr/Mrs Some Guy  !
QUESTION
    Quelle est la sortie du code suivant? print(5 >= 5)
  1 - 5 >= 5
  2 - True
  3 - False
  4 - None
Your choice : 2


QUESTION
    Lequel de ces types de données n’est pas un type de base en Python?
  1 - Lists
  2 - Class
  3 - Dictionary
  4 - Tuples
Your choice : 2
```

Comment: After 5 questions, this is what appears. It doesn't print the score

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Intervenant\Desktop\Projets\Python\Formulaire d'evaluation en Console\main.py", line 43, in <module>
    print("Your score is : ", student.ask_question(setQuestions),"/", len(setQuestions))
TypeError: Student.ask_question() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Answer (score 0):

I have made changes to your code! The method `ask_question` and `ask_answer` should be either a class method (`cls` as the first parameter) or an instance method (`self` as the first parameter). I have chosen them to be the instance methods!

Following code works! **Warning:** As I don't know your complete requirement and I have made some assumptions. The changes are based on assumptions. After the changes, the code gives an output that I can't verify!

File: classEtudiant.py

```
import os

class Student:

    # constructor
    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.score = 0

    def reset_score(self):
        self.score = 0

    # ***********************************************************************************************************
    # we create a file called "candidate" in which the candidate enters his personal informations
    # don't forget to add an "r" before the path otherwise it doesn't work
    def candidate_file(self, name, surname):
        with open(r"candidate.txt", "a") as fileCandidate:
            fileCandidate.write("\n" + "Candidat's name : " + name)
            fileCandidate.write("\n" + "Candidat's surname : " + surname)

        # we then rename this "candidate" file with its name, all in a .txt file
        # os.rename(r"C:\Users\Intervenant\Desktop\Projets\Python\candidate.txt", name+".txt")

    # ***********************************************************************************************************


    # this function takes care of retrieving the answer of a candidate to a question
    def ask_answer(self, min, max):
        answer = input("Your choice : ")

        try:
            answer = int(answer)
            if min <= answer <= max:
                return answer
            print("Enter a number between ", min, "and", max)

        except:
            print("Error ! Please enter a number")

        return self.ask_answer(min, max)

    # ***********************************************************************************************************

    # this function takes care of asking questions to the candidate and counting the number of correct answers
    def ask_question(self, question):
        # question[1] represents the set of possible answers
        choice = question[1]
        # question[2] represents the correct answer
        rightAnswer = question[2]

        print("QUESTION"  )
        print("   ", question[0])

        """
        here len(choice) will calculate the size of the number of possible choices
        in the case of question 1, there are 4 possible choices
        so len(choice) = 3 (from 0 to 3)
        """
        for i in range(len(choice)):
            print(" ", i + 1, "-", choice[i])  # this is to display "2 - True" in question 1 for example


        answer = self.ask_answer(1, len(choice))
        print()

        if choice[answer - 1] == rightAnswer:
            print()
            self.score += 1

    # ***********************************************************************************************************

    def set_questions(self, setQuestions):
        for question in setQuestions:
            self.ask_question(question)



    # the set of questions of the exam
    setQuestions=(
        ("What is the output of the following code? print(5 >= 5) ",
            ("5 >= 5","True","False","None"),
            "True"
        ),
        ("Which of these data types is not a base type in Python?",
            ("Lists","Class","Dictionary","Tuples"),
            "Class"
        ),
        ("What is the output of the following code? min(max(False,-2,-5), 1,5) ",
            ("-5","-2","1","False"),
            "False"
        ),
        ("What is the output of the following code? >>>t = (1, 2, 3) >>>t.append( (4, 5, 6) ) >>>print len(t)",
            ("3","4","6","Error"),
            "Error"
        ),
        ("What is the function that compares the elements of two lists?",
            ("cmp(list1, list2)","eq(list1, list2)","len(list1, list2)","max(list1, list2)"),
            "cmp(list1, list2)"
        )
        )
    # set_questions(setQuestions)
    # print("votre score est : ", self.ask_question(setQuestions),"sur", len(setQuestions))
```

File: main.py

```
# the main file

from classEtudiant import Student


name = input("Enter your name : ")
surname = input("Enter your surname : ")

print()
print("Welcome to the test Mr/Mrs", name, surname, " !")

# initialize a student
student = Student(name, surname)

# record the candidate's personal informations in a file
student.candidate_file(name, surname)

# launch the test

setQuestions=(
        ("Quelle est la sortie du code suivant? print(5 >= 5) ",
            ("5 >= 5","True","False","None"),
            "True"
        ),
        ("Lequel de ces types de données n’est pas un type de base en Python?",
            ("Lists","Class","Dictionary","Tuples"),
            "Class"
        ),
        ("Quelle est la sortie du code suivant? min(max(False,-2,-5), 1,5) ",
            ("-5","-2","1","False"),
            "False"
        ),
        ("Quelle est la sortie du code suivant? >>>t = (1, 2, 3) >>>t.append( (4, 5, 6) ) >>>print len(t)",
            ("3","4","6","ERREUR"),
            "ERREUR"
        ),
        ("Quelle est la fonction qui compare les éléments des deux listes?",
            ("cmp(list1, list2)","eq(list1, list2)","len(list1, list2)","max(list1, list2)"),
            "cmp(list1, list2)"
        )
        )

student.set_questions(setQuestions)

# print the score of the student
print("Your score is : ", student.score, "/", len(setQuestions))
```

Here is the output

```
18/01/2022   20:23.58   /home/mobaxterm/temp  python main.py
Enter your name : Some
Enter your surname : Guy

Welcome to the test Mr/Mrs Some Guy  !
QUESTION
    Quelle est la sortie du code suivant? print(5 >= 5)
  1 - 5 >= 5
  2 - True
  3 - False
  4 - None
Your choice : 2


QUESTION
    Lequel de ces types de données n’est pas un type de base en Python?
  1 - Lists
  2 - Class
  3 - Dictionary
  4 - Tuples
Your choice : 2


QUESTION
    Quelle est la sortie du code suivant? min(max(False,-2,-5), 1,5)
  1 - -5
  2 - -2
  3 - 1
  4 - False
Your choice : 2

QUESTION
    Quelle est la sortie du code suivant? >>>t = (1, 2, 3) >>>t.append( (4, 5, 6) ) >>>print len(t)
  1 - 3
  2 - 4
  3 - 6
  4 - ERREUR
Your choice : 2

QUESTION
    Quelle est la fonction qui compare les éléments des deux listes?
  1 - cmp(list1, list2)
  2 - eq(list1, list2)
  3 - len(list1, list2)
  4 - max(list1, list2)
Your choice : 2

Your score is :  2 / 5
```

Comment: It works. thanks !
I have some questions
Why do you add this after the constructor
`def reset_score(self):
        self.score = 0`

Comment: It is out-of-habit! You might have already tried -- deleting the method will not break the code!